# How to select multiple object in outliner using box selection in 3d viewport?

Tags: selection-tools

I want to select multiple objects in the outliner but in some case, easier for me to select them in 3d viewport (using box selection) and then i want the selection to highlighted in the outliner so then i can drag them around in the outliner panel ? How can i do this ?